# Low power Wheatstone bridge

Tags: low-power, wheatstone-bridge

I'm working on a low-power application (cycling power meter) that will use a Wheatstone bridge in half-bridge configuration to measure strain.  I'd like to run this system from a coin cell (or similarly size Li-ion battery).  Unfortunately, most strain gauges I've found have resistances in the 350-1kohm range, leading to ~mA of current draw.  So far, I have two ideas for conserving power:

1. Use a MOSFET in series with the Wheatstone bridge, turning it on only when we need to make a measurement (sampling at something like 100-1000Hz, with system "on" time depending on settling time of the amplifier output and ADC reading time)
2. Adding a resistor in series with the Wheatstone bridge

Are there other good options for reducing power in a Wheatstone bridge or possibly lower power alternatives?  [This paper](https://hal-lirmm.ccsd.cnrs.fr/lirmm-00498468/document) has an alternative design, but it only saves ~3x power in exchange for a potentially more complex design.

Comment: Taking a reading with a short duty cycle should work, though I'd suggest a lower sample rate, if feasible in your application, to avoid high-frequency issues where it takes too long for the circuit to settle after turning on. Also, a low-leakage supercapacitor across the coin cell would lower peak demand from it.

Comment: I have to do some more experimentation to determine what sample rate will actually work; we may be able to use 50-100.  My plan is to do some tests on duty cycle length using an oscilloscope to try to cut down duty cycle as much as possible.  And thank you for the tip on using a supercapacitor; I will look into that!

Comment: I have done this with a P-channel MOSFET, power up my sensor only when needed. You will need to carefully determine how how long you need to stabilize after applying power before you make the measurement.

Comment: @Mattman944, I know this is highly system-dependent, but can I ask how long your system needed to stabilize?  Did you need to add anything in order to expedite stabilization?

Comment: @d.slotcavage - I have it set for 1 mS, probably longer than necessary since I wanted to it to be long enough to see the LED (LED, opto-diode sensor). I would think that 100 uS would work for my system, maybe lower. But, it has no caps, do you have a filter cap before the ADC? That could be the limiting factor. Also, you have a very low power voltage, you may need to boost it to have enough gate voltage for the MOSFET. Do you run the voltage booster all the time, or switch it also? It may be very slow.